# How to 'remember' combo selection after inserting new Item (LINQ to SQL)?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, linq

So I'm using the ASP.NET LINQ to SQL Website template in VS 2010. My site is functioning as is expected, but I'm trying to make some customizations that are a little over my head. The user is originally presented with two selections...

Departments | Employees

Based on their selection they are presented with a page where they can insert a new item (Department or Employee). Here is my issue...

If I click Departments and select Department_A, I see all the employees within Department_A and I know I'm looking at Department_A because the combo box at the top of the page shows me this. At this point I select Insert New Item, Save my New Employee, and then I am taken back to "All" Departments, instead of back to Department_A, which is where I just left. My goal is to not have to have someone click back into a Department should they need to add multiple employees for the same department.

Any ideas?

**SOLUTION:**
Here is the code used to achieve my goal, in Insert.aspx.vb...

```
Protected table As MetaTable

Public Shared Function getPassedVars() As String
    Dim oParams As String = ""
    Dim qString As String = ""
    Dim oSplit As New List(Of String)
    Try
        With HttpContext.Current
            qString = .Request.Url.Query
            If qString.Length > 0 Then 'do we have any passed variables?
                oSplit.AddRange(qString.Split("&"))
                    For i As Integer = 0 To oSplit.Count - 1
                        oParams &= String.Format("{0}{1}", oSplit.Item(i), IIf(i < oSplit.Count - 1, ";", ""))
                    Next
                    Return oParams
                Else
                    Return Nothing
                End If
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    table = DynamicDataRouteHandler.GetRequestMetaTable(Context)
    FormView1.SetMetaTable(table, table.GetColumnValuesFromRoute(Context))
    DetailsDataSource.EntityTypeName = table.EntityType.AssemblyQualifiedName
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Title = table.DisplayName
End Sub

Protected Sub FormView1_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = DataControlCommands.CancelCommandName Then
        Response.Redirect(table.ListActionPath + getPassedVars())
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub FormView1_ItemInserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormViewInsertedEventArgs)
    If e.Exception Is Nothing OrElse e.ExceptionHandled Then
        Dim urlVars As String
        For Each s As String In Request.QueryString
            urlVars = "?" & (s & "=") + Request.QueryString(s)
        Next

        Response.Redirect(table.ListActionPath & urlVars)

    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using to perform the action I needed.

In Insert.aspx.vb, I added this code to the FormView_ItemInserted Sub...

```
    For Each s As String In Request.QueryString
           urlVars = "?" & (s & "=") + Request.QueryString(s)
    Next

    Response.Redirect(table.ListActionPath & urlVars)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a Session to track where you're at and then checking that Session against the logic you want to use? http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/57/

Comment: Sounds relevant. Not sure I completely understand how to implement it. I will do some more reading on it. Thanks for the suggestion. I think the reason it does not go back to the Department_A view I would prefer, is because Department_A is not an actual Table. Employees is the Table, the Department is simply a Filter at that point I believe?

Comment: No. This sounds like more like something that is happening in your backend code. It sounds like the form processor is doing a Response.Redirect back to the main page once the item is processed.

Comment: Protected Sub FormView1_ItemInserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormViewInsertedEventArgs)                                    
        If e.Exception Is Nothing OrElse e.ExceptionHandled Then
            Response.Redirect(table.ListActionPath)
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: You either need to change the process of your "Save my New Employee" button or create a different button called "Add another employee" and create the process for that. Forget what I said about Sessions that was a little bit of an overkill.  Look for a Sub that has the name of your button and start there.

Comment: yes, it is doing what it is suppose to do. I would prefer that it redirect to the very last view though. In all reality it's the same view, but with the DynamicFilter combo set to the department originally selected. How could I change it so that that combo doesn't change to "All" upon saving?

Comment: That's probably where a Session would come in. What is the URL when your combo box is set?  Does it have something like www.expample.com?id=employeea or something like that?  If it does then you need to recreate the url in your Response.Redirect.  That's where the session comes in because you can store what combo box you are on and then refer to the session variable in the Response.Redirect.

Comment: http://localhost:54001/wcPhones/Employees/List.aspx & http://localhost:54001/wcPhones/Employees/Insert.aspx?dept_ID=2 -- It is set in both of these to Department_A

Comment: ok, I was able to do kind of what your insinuating by using Response.Redirect(table.ListActionPath + "?dept_ID=" & "2"), can I replace "2" with the ID of the label currently in the combo at the Insert page?

Comment: Ok. Then look at both List.aspx and List.aspx.vb and see how it's changing to Department_A. Once you have that, you'll need to recreate the URL used in the Response.Redirect in the Insert.aspx.vb.  Most likely there is a Response.Request("dept_ID") in the Insert.aspx.vb and I would use that as part of the URL just because the id will change depending on department.

Comment: every occurrence of response.redirect is simply to table.ListActionPath, never does it actually show it attaching the dept_ID

Comment: When you choose the department do you need to hit a submit button to do to the next step or does it just automatically show you the form?

If it automatically shows you the form, then there is a onchange going on in the select. That's where the Response.Request would kick in because it has to find the dept_ID.

If it requires a sumbit button then there is a value being recorded by the select. You need to look at the variable for the select. So it would be variable.text that would hold the department id value.

Comment: Selection process is... click Departments, then I get a list of all departments, at which point I click "View Employees" for the department I want, then I get a list of all employees in that department (url=List.aspx?dept_ID=X" also on this employee list page there is a combo box with the department I have selected. No submit buttons at any point.

Comment: lonehorseend: thanks for all your help, although I didn't use any of your recommendations, your thought process assisted me in determining how to proceed.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help in even that way. Now that I'm reading through my stuff, I realize that I was throwing a little bit of curve ball by making Request a property of Response instead of the independent command that it is.